# Java 8 way to convert int[][] to Integer[][]

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, java-8

How to convert `java` `int[][]` to  `Integer[][]` ? .It seems easy to convert single dimensional primitive array to Object type single dimensional array using java stream.

For example

```
Integer[] result = IntStream.of( intarray ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
```

Is there any way for two dimensional array like above ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the same thing within a `map` operation

```
int[][] twoDimenArray = {};
Integer[][] result = Stream.of(twoDimenArray)
    .map(array -> IntStream.of(array).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new))
    .toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) method:

```java
int[][] arr1 = {};

Integer[][] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row)
                .boxed()
                .toArray(Integer[]::new))
        .toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```